# how to use numpy array in function

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, function

So, I have a numpy array as such

```
angle_array = np.arange(20, 61, 1)
```

And I have a function of

```
def sim_projectile(time_array,m,c,v0,theta0d)
```

The function has two outputs.

```
return position_x, position_y
```

The variables time_array, m, c and v0 have been defined. The elements in angle_array are equivalent to theta0d. How would I feed the elements in angle_array to the function for it to process all the elements in angle_array and spit out two outputs for each angle?

Comment: You'd have to call the function seperately for each of those elements.  something like `[sim_projectile(time_array, m, c, v0, theta0d) for theta0d in angle_array]`